# duplicate file with different name and folder via batch

Tags: batch-file

I want to copy a file to a user defined folder with different filename via batch file

Here folder path is supplied by argument

CODE

```
type abc > %1\\my_abc
```

but it does nothing than creating file in same folder

whats my mistake?

Comment: Is `%1` empty?  The copy command doesn't create folders so your `%1` folder will have to exist already.   The \\ should be a single \ in this case, though it works in many cases with \\

Comment: no its not empty. i pass the argument to it

Comment: Does the %1 folder\path already exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use :

```
copy abc %1\my_abc
```